# In Angular 15.2.4, ngx-mat-timepicker is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, timepicker

In my Angular 15.2.4 project ngx-material-timepicker is not working.

It's imported in my app.module.ts:

```
 `import { NgxMatTimepickerModule } from 'ngx-mat-timepicker';
   @NgModule({
  imports: [NgxMatTimepickerModule]
  })
```

my component.html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>TIMEPICKER</mat-label>
    <input matInput [ngxMatTimepicker]="picker" />
    <ngx-mat-timepicker #picker></ngx-mat-timepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

It's showing this error:

> 'ngx-mat-timepicker' is not a known element (used in the 'Component'
> component template):
>
> 1. If 'ngx-mat-timepicker' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
> 2. If 'ngx-mat-timepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message. v

Comment: In which module is your component declared? This is the module where you need to import `NgxMatTimepickerModule`.

Comment: If your component is a `Standalone` you can simply import that module in the component's decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import it into each module that uses the picker.

Comment: I am import in  app.module.ts file